# Can you define a variable name by the input of the user in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So i have a command that displays a variable by what the user typed in.
For example if a user wanted to know (in my code) the plan for "Moderators" The user would write !plan Moderators and what it would do is printing the plan for Moderators by doing: message.channel.send(`${plan_}${args[2]}`) (the mark is from the code thingies) But i also want a command that creates a command like this: !plan create Administrator (plan) So what this would do is make a variable called plan_Administrator and assign the variable to the value of the plan

But how?

`plan_(args[3])` ???

Comment: What do you have right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called using dynamic variable names: to do this, you'll need to use an `eval` statement, which is highly recommended since it exposes your code to an injection attack. I'll show you how to do it anyway, but be aware that holding the properties inside an object is way safer.

To create variables with dynamic names you'll need to make your code evaluate a sentence like this: `var (varName) = (value)`. It will look something like this:

```js
// name and value should be your arguments from the command
eval('var ' + name + ' = ' + value)

// Be aware that the only way to access the variable is by using the global scope:
let myValue = global[variableName]
```

More secure way to do this, using a dictionary:

```js
// Somewhere in your code so that is accessible by commands
let userVariables = {}

// When you want to access a variable
let myValue = userVariables[varName]

// When you want to set a variable
userVariables[varName] = yourValue
```

Comment: Thank you, kind of forgot about this post, sorry
Also i don't know if you were sarcastic about the part you were talking about my code being exposed to an injection attack but ill go for the safer version.

Comment: @agentORW No no, I'm dead serious about the injection issue. Imagine your user types something like `a=1;console.log('other code');a`: there are no spaces, so everything is interpreted as the `name` argument, and you end up evaluating a code that assigns the `a` variable but also runs the `console.log`. Now imagine that instead of logging to the console they decide to close the process, expose your token, or just make the bot do anything: by injecting the code there they literally can do everything that is possible within the scope of your `eval` function. A dictionary solves the issue ;)

Comment: Ok! I will make sure to do the better soulution. Btw how do you add things to the dic ? I found a way to do it online wich is: `plans[name] = args[2]` but that resets the whole thing to only being that so when i try to make a command that prints it, it says that i cant send an empty message. Aslo when i try to add multiple it also doesnt work and replaces the whole dic

Comment: If you 're using different `name` parameters it can't replace the whole dict...

Comment: What I mean is that this dictionary is just a normal object, it doesn't have anything special, and so it shouldn't be possible for weird things to happen